# Print from UIWebView - Swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I need to view a form on a webpage, through a UIWebView on an iPad app. After the user submits the form, I need to send a print job from the form on the webpage through to an AirPrint enabled printer on the same wifi network as the iPad. I have access to do anything I need to on the website. I have read that the UIWebView cannot recognise the window.print() JavaScript command.

What can I do to get the iPad app to receive a print job and print via AirPrint?
I have seen that other people on this website have asked similar questions, but none of them have been answered with much detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample project by Apple on printing UIwebView content.

[Print Web View Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PrintWebView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010311)

```
- (IBAction)printWebPage:(id)sender
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if(!controller){
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };


    // Obtain a printInfo so that we can set our printing defaults.
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    // This application produces General content that contains color.
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    // We'll use the URL as the job name.
    printInfo.jobName = [self.urlField text];
    // Set duplex so that it is available if the printer supports it. We are
    // performing portrait printing so we want to duplex along the long edge.
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    // Use this printInfo for this print job.
    controller.printInfo = printInfo;

    // Be sure the page range controls are present for documents of > 1 page.
    controller.showsPageRange = YES;

    // This code uses a custom UIPrintPageRenderer so that it can draw a header and footer.
    APLPrintPageRenderer *myRenderer = [[APLPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
    // The APLPrintPageRenderer class provides a jobtitle that it will label each page with.
    myRenderer.jobTitle = printInfo.jobName;
    // To draw the content of each page, a UIViewPrintFormatter is used.
    UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [self.myWebView viewPrintFormatter];

#if SIMPLE_LAYOUT
    /*
     For the simple layout we simply set the header and footer height to the height of the
     text box containing the text content, plus some padding.

     To do a layout that takes into account the paper size, we need to do that
     at a point where we know that size. The numberOfPages method of the UIPrintPageRenderer
     gets the paper size and can perform any calculations related to deciding header and
     footer size based on the paper size. We'll do that when we aren't doing the simple
     layout.
     */
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:HEADER_FOOTER_TEXT_HEIGHT];
    CGSize titleSize = [myRenderer.jobTitle sizeWithFont:font];
    myRenderer.headerHeight = myRenderer.footerHeight = titleSize.height + HEADER_FOOTER_MARGIN_PADDING;
#endif
    [myRenderer addPrintFormatter:viewFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
    // Set our custom renderer as the printPageRenderer for the print job.
    controller.printPageRenderer = myRenderer;

    /*
     The method we use to present the printing UI depends on the type of UI idiom that is currently executing. Once we invoke one of these methods to present the printing UI, our application's direct involvement in printing is complete. Our custom printPageRenderer will have its methods invoked at the appropriate time by UIKit.
     */
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPad
    }
    else {
        [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPhone
    }
}
```